# Highlight a specific part in <textarea> using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and I cannot understand what they write in other questions, like this punctuation($). Can anyone give me the easiest way to do this or at least show me what should I learn to do this?

My first idea was to generate an element and then color it. After that,  I replaced the value of the text area with the text content of the element.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function active1() {
        var w = document.getElementById("infor");
        var z = document.getElementById("infor").value;
        var h = z.length;
        var u = document.getElementById("search").value;
        var q = u.length;
        var answer = [];
        var string ="";
        for(var i = 0;i<h;i++)
        {
            for(var t=0;t < q; t++)
            {
                if(z[i+t] === u[t])
                {
                    answer.push(z[t+i]);
                    if(answer.length === q)
                    {
                        var b = i + t; 
                        for(var v in answer)
                        {
                            string += answer[v];
                        }    
                        var create = document.createElement("p");
                        create.textContent = string;
                        create.id = "get";
                        document.getElementById("bye").appendChild(create);
                        var get = document.getElementById("get");
                        var a = z.replace(z.substr(i,b),get.innerHTML);
                        w.style.color = "red";
                        var y = document.createElement("p");
                        y.innerHTML = create.innerHTML;
                        document.getElementById("superman").appendChild(y);
                        w.value = a;
                        break;  
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    answer = [];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="search" id="search" placeholder="type here">
<input type = "button" value="search" onclick="active1()"/>
<textarea rows="50" cols = "100" id="infor"></textarea>
<div id="bye"></div>
<div id="superman"><div>
```

Comment: $ is used in JQuery and you aren't using it according to your code but anyway it's used for selecting DOM elements  and the best site to learn from is [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: of course i have never known how to use it, how do i suppose to use it in my code

Comment: Please explain exactly what expectations are and what the current code needs to do differently. A textrea only contains text and no html that can be used to highlight with

Comment: I think he means select text

Comment: That's my mistake, at first i thought that when i do this through javascript. Not only text but also style can be kept through transform processing inside JS. But i was totally wrong. It only kept text when i appended value from JS to textarea. And this mistake allured me to a hole which took me one day to escape from it.

Comment: @NguyễnThếVinh, just as a suggestion doing these kind of jobs in pure JS ( selecting an element with specific id ) are really tedious compared to how easily they could be handled in JQuery and later if you use Ajax you will see how perfect it is used in JQuery.

Comment: I will always remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` operator is related to JQuery. To use JQuery in your code you must add this line at the end of `<body>` tag or in `head` section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In order to use JQuery here is an example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
       });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the answer to your exercise :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>hi</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#clickme").click(function() {
        $("body").append('<p id="gen" style="color:red">'+$("#getme").val()+'</p>');
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="getme" type="text" placeholder="Content here..." />
  <button id="clickme">Click!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: i can see that you wrote "#clickme". Can you define "#" for me pls ?

Comment: Are you familiar with CSS? In CSS for accessing an element with a particular id you use `#id` and for a particular class you use `.class`. JQuery uses CSS selector with some addon selectors like `:even` ant etc. which aren't available in CSS.

Comment: Oh, that's how it works, thanks you so much for your help.